# Javascript: How to get id of div from dynamically added tab and call a function with that?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs, parameter-passing

I've got a webpage on which I can dynamically create new tabs in which a chat with a selected user is/should be initiated. I wrote and tested the chat-script on itself, which works perfectly well and I now need to integrate it with the tabs.

So I've got this function which adds a new tab. In this function I set the tab-pane id to the user_id:

```
function addTab(user_id, name) {
    $('#pageTab').append(
        $('<li><a href="#' + user_id + '">' + name +
            '<button class="close" type="button">×</button></a></li>'));
    $('#pageTabContent').append($('<div class="tab-pane" id="' + user_id 
        +'"><form id="send_message_form"><textarea id="messageText" rows="1" cols="25"></textarea></br>'
        + '<input type="button" id="sendButton" value="Send Message"></form>'
        + '<div class="conversation"></div></div>'));
    $('#page' + user_id).tab('show');
}
```

I then also have a function which updates the chat within this tab. In here I need the user_id (from the tab-pane):

```
// Poll for new messages
function updateConversation(){
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        accepts: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "/api/support/{{ supporter_id }}",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            'action': 'GET_MESSAGES',
            'user_id': user_id,
            'last_message_id':last_message_id
        }),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.messages.length > 0){
                for (var i=0; i<data.messages.length; i++){
                    $(".conversation").prepend("<P>"+ data.messages[i].text + "</p>");
                    last_message_id = data.messages[i].id;
                }
            }
        }
    });
    setTimeout(updateConversation, 1000);
}
```

So my question is: how would I be able to get the id from the tab-pane that is selected, and then pass it to the updateConversation() function?

I'm kinda lost here, so all tips are welcome!

Comment: Did you try the `.on()` method? http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @Sebsemillia - Ehm, no. But where would you suggest I would use that?

Comment: Within the function that calls `updateConversation()`, get the ID from the dynamically generated tab with an `.on()` event handler (maybe you need to create a custom event for that, depending on how your function that calls `updateConversation()` is called. And than just pass the ID variable to your `updateConversation()` function.

Comment: Is this using jQuery UI tabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you need...

```
// Poll for new messages
function updateConversation(){
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        accepts: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "/api/support/{{ supporter_id }}",
        data: JSON.stringify({
            'action': 'GET_MESSAGES',
            'user_id': $(".tab-pane:visible")[0].id,
            'last_message_id':last_message_id
        }),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.messages.length > 0){
                for (var i=0; i<data.messages.length; i++){
                    $(".conversation")
                        .prepend("<p>"+ data.messages[i].text + "</p>")
                        .data("last-message-id", data.messages[i].id);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    setTimeout(updateConversation, 1000);
}
```

I've changed the variable `user_id` to this...

`$("div.tab-pane:visible")[0].id`

That gets the id of the visible div with class `tab-pane` and uses it as the user_id variable in the data object you send via your ajax call.

I've also modified it to save the message ID as a data attribute on the conversation list, so to get the ID of the last message for the visible tab, you could use...

```
var lastMessageID = $(".tab-pane:visible .conversation").data("last-message-id");
```

Comment: Awesome!! Works like a charm! One more question; I also need to get the id of the last message which I got from the api. I normally saved it in a variable, but since I now use several tabs, where and how do I store it? Or would I be able to somehow also append it to the list of messages, and then simply get it from there?

Comment: I've modified it to store that ID on the conversation div when it adds the last message.  That way you've got all the last message IDs available, regardless of whether they're visible or not (if you need them for anything else).